# Creating a "face" code with manipulation capabilities

Tags: java, user-interface

I have an assignment where I am supposed to create a prototype drawing program to display and manipulate faces. It is supposed to use 2 windows, one to draw the face and the other to control the drawing. It is supposed to initially show the image of a face (drawn with shapes).

The face consists of a head, two eyes, a nose, and a mouth. Each of these parts is selected by clicking the mouse within the border of the object. The eyes are selected as a pair, so clicking either eye selects them both. when one face part is selected, all previous selections are forgotten.

The control window operates only upon the selected object. A click on the Change image button performs the following tasks (depending on the selected face part):

- Head: Head changes from green to yellow to purple to purple, and back to green
- Nose: The nose image changes another of three possible nose images
- Mouth: Mouth image changes to another of three possible mouth images
- Eyes: eye image changes to another of four possible eye images

Include a scroll bar with behavior:

- Selected Head: Head gets wider and narrower with scroll bar value change
- Selected Nose: Nose image moves up or down with scroll bar value change
- Selected Mouth: Mouth gets wider or narrower with scroll bar value change
- Selected Eyes: Eyes move closer together or farther apart with scroll bar value change

My problem is, I have no idea where to even start. I have watched many a tutorial on swing and awt and have even tried playing around with the palette manager in NetBeans. Can anyone point me in the right direction or maybe walk me through the code?

Comment: If your instructor is giving you this type of assignment, but you as a student have absolutely no idea where to start, then either A) You need to pay closer attention in class, or B) You need to have a serious discussion with your instructor about his/her teaching practices.

Comment: I couldn't agree with you more. I have tried several times actually. I have set up up multiple meetings with the instructor and get the same result every time: "Check google." Whenever I email him a specific question he responds with something totally irrelevant and doesn't even come close to answering it. I have asked and asked and have scrutinized online resources but still haven't found anything very helpful, hence why I came here. I'm not necessarily looking for the assignment to be done for me, I just want to understand it.

Comment: Can the eyes, nose, mouth, and head be rectangles?

Comment: I believe they have to be circles, with the exception of the nose which looks like it should be a free-form polyline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not a good fit here. Also, despite your instructors alleged inaccuracies, it is still conceivably possible for a person to do the research on their own to go from the rather nice set of specific requirements you have to a functioning program. I don't mean that to be as critical as it may sound.

However, out of appreciation of the fact that you approached your instructor, and also out of pity, maybe I can give you some starting points and hints.

First of all, Swing is the right way to start. Read through the relevant sections of the tutorial at http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javaswingtutorial/ and follow along with some of the projects.

You can code Swing interfaces by hand quite easily, and for your relatively simple application, and for the learning experience, it is a reasonable option. However, for future reference, many IDEs have GUI editors (NetBeans ships with the feature I think, Eclipse has the WindowBuilder plugin) - the caveat being that you have to add learning how to use the IDE to your task list (of course, this will ultimately save you time in the long run).

In any case, your first step should be to *design* your software. Determine what actions you need to perform, what user actions you need to respond to and how, and what information you are working with. You give the following requirements:

> The control window operates only upon the selected object. A click on
>   the Change image button performs the following tasks (depending on the
>   selected face part):
>
> - Head: Head changes from green to yellow to purple to purple, and back
>     to green
> - Nose: The nose image changes another of three possible nose
>     images
> - Mouth: Mouth image changes to another of three possible mouth
>     images
> - Eyes: eye image changes to another of four possible eye images
>
> Include a scroll bar with behavior:
>
> - Selected Head: Head gets wider and narrower with scroll bar value
>     change
> - Selected Nose: Nose image moves up or down with scroll bar
>     value change
> - Selected Mouth: Mouth gets wider or narrower with scroll
>     bar value change
> - Selected Eyes: Eyes move closer together or farther
>     apart with scroll bar value change

The basic component you are working with here is a face, so let's make a design decision here to have a face be an object with other properties (you could take a different approach and have the different parts of the face be your basic units). Based on your description of scroll bars, a face has the following modifiable properties:

- Head width.
- Vertical nose position.
- Mouth width.
- Distance between eyes.

A face also, of course, has other constant characteristics that are pretty much up to you to arbitrarily decide the value of, for example the diameter of the eyes, the color of the skin, etc. You will have to work those out.

In addition to modifying the above properties, there are a few things you need to be able to do with a face, also based directly on your requirements:

- Draw (paint) the face.
- Redraw (repaint) the face when a property changes.
- Allow the user to select a part by clicking, which breaks down into:

  - Responding to mouse clicks.
  - Determining the component under the cursor given an XY location.
  - Providing information about the selection to the application.

The last part "providing information about the selection" is an implementation detail that you have a few options for, and you will have to decide. For example, you could create some type of event listener interface and tell the face about it, and let it call methods on that interface when the selection changes -- this is a very swing way to do it. You could also have the face internally maintain which property is currently selected, in which case you need to give it the ability to get/set the value of the currently selected property. You could also have the face directly call methods on your editor UI window. All of these ways have distinct advantages and disadvantages, and I'll leave it as an exercise to the reader to experiment.

Now, you also, as per your requirements, need to provide a scroll bar for the user to edit properties with, in a separate window. So now, think about what UI components you need and how you want them to tie together:

- Face Window

  - Contains a single face component (or more if you want).
- Editor Window

  - Contains a scroll bar.
  - Might contain a label describing the current selection, if you'd like.

Swing already provides most of these components. A window is a `JFrame`. A scroll bar is a `JScrollBar`. A label is a `JLabel`. Swing doesn't provide a face, so you'll need to write a custom component yourself.

As for how they tie together:

- Changing the object selection in the face could:

  - Update the scrollbar to the current value, if you'd like.
  - Update the scrollbar range to appropriate values.
  - Update the label to describe the current selection, if you'd like.
- Changing the scrollbar must:

  - Update the currently selected property on the face.
  - Ultimately cause the face to be redrawn.

The major task now, then, is to implement a Swing component that draws a face and responds to mouse clicks.

Since you are creating a new component, you'll want to pick an appropriate base, perhaps a `JComponent` or a `JPanel`, up to you. Exactly how to create new components can be easily found in many tutorials on Google (including some basics in the one I linked to above), and that is up to you to research. Essentially, though, reiterating what was said above, your custom face component has the following custom behaviors:

- [Draw a face.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics%29)
- [Receive mouse events](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#addMouseListener%28java.awt.event.MouseListener%29).
- Determine clicked component from mouse X,Y coordinates. At its most basic level, this will require some math. If your head, eyes, mouth, and nose are ellipses, for example, it will be up to you to compute whether or not a given X,Y coordinate is within the bounds of one of those ellipses. However, you will want to look into [Shape](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html), which will allow you to easily define shapes and provides bounds checking methods already.

I think this is enough for you to get started and put it all together. The following general tasks are at hand:

- Read that tutorial I linked to, a lot of basics should become clear. Try writing some simple "hello world" style applications.
- Try writing some custom components; your requirements are basic and much of it is covered in the "Painting" section of that tutorial.
- Check out a tutorial or some examples on how to use `Shape` and experiment.

If you have specific questions about code you've written, with a specific problem you may be trying to solve, you can always come back and post that on SO.

I hope this helps. More importantly, I hope this gives you at least some idea of how to go from requirements to implementation in general.

Edit:

It's been a while since I played with `Shape` so I put together this tiny example. Click / drag over the two shapes to select them, which will turn them yellow:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ShapeSelect extends JPanel {

    private final Shape firstShape = new Rectangle2D.Float(60, 40, 70, 70);
    private final Shape secondShape = new Ellipse2D.Float(30, 30, 90, 50);
    private Shape selected = null;

    public ShapeSelect () {
        // set up the component
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            @Override public void mouseDragged (MouseEvent event) {
                selectShapeUnder(event.getX(), event.getY());
            }
        });
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override public void mousePressed (MouseEvent event) {
                selectShapeUnder(event.getX(), event.getY());
            }
        });
    }

    // draw our shapes, selected shape is yellow.
    @Override protected void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D)g;
        graphics.setColor((selected == firstShape) ? Color.YELLOW : Color.RED);
        graphics.fill(firstShape);
        graphics.setColor((selected == secondShape) ? Color.YELLOW : Color.GREEN);
        graphics.fill(secondShape);
    }

    // updates 'selected' based on x,y coordinate and redraws component on change.
    public void selectShapeUnder (int x, int y) {
        Shape oldSelected = selected;
        // note that since second shape is draw on top of first, we give second preference.
        // for overlapping shapes the selection should be consistent with the gui display.
        if (secondShape.contains(x, y))
            selected = secondShape;
        else if (firstShape.contains(x, y))
            selected = firstShape;
        else
            selected = null;
        if (selected != oldSelected)
            repaint();
    }


    public static final void main (String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run () {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Shape Select");
                frame.getContentPane().add(new ShapeSelect(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }


}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That definitely gives me a better idea. I'll check out those tutorials and see what I can put together. I'll re-post if I have further issues. Thanks a lot for the help, I appreciate it!

Comment: I added a short example of drawing a `Shape` and checking coordinates.